# if - else if Condition checking BUG

Tags: java, android

Lets say we have two variables that are

```
int number = 0;
int second_number = 1;
```

If we dont use brackets in if-else if check like this.

```
if(number == 1)
    if(second_number == 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Haha!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if(number == 0)
    if(second_number == 1)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hehe!", Tast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**else if(number == 0) line is never reached** so that program not working decently and even there is no warning for this usage! I've been figured this bug after like fighting for 2 hours!

However code works if you use brackets like this.

```
if(number == 1) {
    if(second_number == 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Haha!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(number == 0) {
    if(second_number == 1)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hehe!", Tast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Is this behaviour intentional or just a bad bug? If this is a bug can you send google to a bug report because i don't know how to.

Comment: yes, you should better using the `brackets` to prevent any mistake like you did here and in future if you developing a complex and larger application or web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Documentation, this is called "Dangling Else Problem", It's not a bug its normal java behavior [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5).

```
if (number == 1)
    if (second_number == 0)
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Haha!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if(number == 0) // A "dangling else"
```

To Overcome this you can use like this,

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

Comment: Thats a Good one +1.

Comment: Oh now im convinced, i still think this is sort of miss for c and java creators and when they figured this out it was too late to correct it, however thanks for the answer im accepting it!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use brackets if you have more than one expression inside an IF

```
if(true)
    works;


if(true)
   dont;
   work;

 //work is executed even if the condition doesn't pass, because the IF isn't wrapping it


if(true){
   works;
   too;
}
```

Edit: The problem is that the if  inside the first consumes the else if, if this were python, or any indent based language, it should work

```
if(second_number == 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Haha!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if(number == 0)
```

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't there an error or at least a warning message in android studio?

Comment: no, because the syntax is correct, the IF is wrapping only the first expression

Comment: Well, i still believe that this should be reported. Can you give me a link to report this? Then i will accept your answer.

Comment: Actually, the problem with your code is not what I pointed, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how you indent your code. The else belongs to the the if immediately above it. You have to use curly brackets all the time, especially if you have nested if-else statements